# Why won't my EditText element accept any input on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textselection

Here's the code for my EditText element:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/myTextEdit"/>
```

The entire app builds and I'm not using this element in code yet, but when it shows up on the screen I cannot type into the element.

This EditText element will not accept text any time I try to type into it.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire reason it fails is because the EditText element is already selectable.
For some reason adding the following property causes the element to be uneditable:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

I removed the property from the layout and I could type text into the element.